# PHP array_key_exists returning FALSE incorrectly

Tags: php, array-key-exists

My data is being pulled from a client's CMS, but I'm getting strange results

```
print_r($appliance_data);
foreach ($appliance_data as $adKey => $adValue) {
    print_r($adKey);
    print_r($adValue);
    print_r(array_key_exists($adKey, $appliance_data));
    print_r(isset($appliance_data[$adKey]));
}
```

With output

```
Array
(
    [94] => stdClass Object
        (
            [operation] => 0
            [value] => 0
        )

    [102] => stdClass Object
        (
            [operation] => 501
            [value] => 4
        )

    [90] => stdClass Object
        (
            [operation] => 0
            [value] => 0
        )
)
94
stdClass Object
(
    [operation] => 0
    [value] => 0
)
(boolean) FALSE
(boolean) FALSE
102
stdClass Object
(
    [operation] => 501
    [value] => 4
)
(boolean) FALSE
(boolean) FALSE
90
stdClass Object
(
    [operation] => 0
    [value] => 0
)
(boolean) FALSE
(boolean) FALSE
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Edit:  The error is that array_key_exists AND isset **return FALSE for a key obtained by looping over an array!**

```
serialize($appliance_data)



a:7:{s:2:"94";O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:9:"operation";s:3:"514";s:5:"value";s:1:"2";s:9:"frequency";s:1:"0";}s:3:"102";O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:9:"operation";s:3:"511";s:5:"value";s:1:"4";s:9:"frequency";s:1:"1";}s:2:"90";O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:9:"operation";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:1:"0";s:9:"frequency";s:1:"0";}s:2:"68";O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:9:"operation";s:3:"501";s:5:"value";s:1:"3";s:9:"frequency";s:1:"2";}s:2:"66";O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:9:"operation";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:1:"0";s:9:"frequency";s:1:"0";}s:2:"84";O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:9:"operation";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:1:"0";s:9:"frequency";s:1:"0";}s:2:"98";O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:9:"operation";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:1:"0";s:9:"frequency";s:1:"0";}}
```

Comment: Some of your code is odd (won't run as it is - too many brackets after print_r()). The loop bit looks like it ought to run fine, whereas the last line should cause an error. Can you confirm this by running it? I get the loop running fine when I try similar code.

Comment: @Matt, The extra bracket was due to the code being deep within a clients CMS.  The array is provided by the client CMS, so I'm thinking its encoded incorrectly!

Answer (score 5):

You are using a string '94' instead of an int 94. Try:

```
print_r(array_key_exists(94, $appliance_data));
```

**Edit:** I can't reproduce this locally at all - can anyone else?

I tried to replicate this with the following code:

```
$first = new stdClass();
$first->operation = 0;
$first->value = 0;
$second = new stdClass();
$second->operation = 501;
$second->value = 4;
$third = new stdClass();
$third->operation = 0;
$third->value = 0;

$appliance_data = array(94 => $first, 102 => $second, 90 => $third);
// Same output when using these lines too:
// $appliance_data = array('94' => $first, '102' => $second, '90' => $third);
// $appliance_data = array("94" => $first, "102" => $second, "90" => $third);

print_r($appliance_data);
echo "\n\n";
foreach ($appliance_data as $adKey => $adValue) {
    print_r($adKey);
    echo "\n";
    print_r($adValue);
    print_r(array_key_exists($adKey, $appliance_data));
    echo "\n";
    print_r(isset($appliance_data[$adKey]));
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

And got this output:

```
Array
(
    [94] => stdClass Object
        (
            [operation] => 0
            [value] => 0
        )

    [102] => stdClass Object
        (
            [operation] => 501
            [value] => 4
        )

    [90] => stdClass Object
        (
            [operation] => 0
            [value] => 0
        )

)


94
stdClass Object
(
    [operation] => 0
    [value] => 0
)
1
1

102
stdClass Object
(
    [operation] => 501
    [value] => 4
)
1
1

90
stdClass Object
(
    [operation] => 0
    [value] => 0
)
1
1
```

Comment: It's not a string in the loop though?

Comment: Yes, the loop still looks weird.

Comment: I suspect this is not directly copy pasted, due to lines like print_r($adValue));
which has too many brackets.

Comment: Do you need to reset the array index when calling `array_key_exists` in a loop? What happens using `isset()`

Comment: Good catch: according to a comment on the man page here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php by manhon824, you do need to call reset() first. I tried similar code however, and it worked for the loop structure.

Comment: Calling `reset($appliance_data)` yields the exact same output.  The problem isn't arrays in general, but this specific array I get from a client

Comment: @Matt, According to http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php , `Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8`, so your answer is incorrect

Comment: @Zeophlite Can you post actual code that reproduces this? I can't make it happen like you describe. Perhaps you could add the result of serialize($appliance_data); ?

Comment: @Zeophlite I tried with $appliance_data = unserialize($yourdata); and got the same result. Is the code in your answer *exactly* the same as the code producing the error?

Comment: @MattGibson, The outputs are wrapped in a method that writes to the screen, but this indirection is necessary as the data is from within the CMS.